# Compute rolling mean/standard deviation with different start date with rollaply

Tags: r, xts, zoo

Is there a *start* argument to the `rollaply` function from the `zoo` package? I would like to compute the columns' standard deviation of a data frame but with a different starting date for each column.

How I compute the standard deviation by columns for a large data frame:

```
library(zoo)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(runif(120),runif(120)))
StDev <-rollapply(dat,12,sd,by=12,na.rm=T,by.column=TRUE, align='right',fill=c(NULL,NULL,NULL))
```

I would like to have the rollaply to start at different rows of the the data frame but hardcoding it like this will take a very long time:

```
SD1 <-rollapply(dat$X1[1:120],12,sd,by=12,na.rm=T, align='right',fill=c(NULL,NULL,NULL)) #start at the first row
SD2 <-rollapply(dat$X1[12:120],12,sd,by=12,na.rm=T, align='right',fill=c(NULL,NULL,NULL)) #start at the 12th row

StDev <-cbind(SD1,c(NA,SD2))

> StDev_desired 
       SD1          SD2
  [1,] 0.2717607        NA
  [2,] 0.2848454 0.2869931
  [3,] 0.3024353 0.3036127
  [4,] 0.1919298 0.1954726
  [5,] 0.3427318 0.3097042
  [6,] 0.3513110 0.3468135
  [7,] 0.3205552 0.3485802
  [8,] 0.2594149 0.2575002
  [9,] 0.3159097 0.3095329
  [10,] 0.2967858 0.2786670
```

I would like to be able to pass to the rolling function a vector with the starting rows.. I could potentially align my data set first (move up the observations in columns I want the rolling function to start later than the rest) but I would like to know if there is a neater alternative.

In stata, the `-rolling-` function as a `start` argument that does it.

Comment: `rollapply` doesn't have a `start` argument (as you likely guessed by looking at the documentation).  You provided sample input and a sample function call, but an example or your desired output would be most helpful.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich. I edited the post with a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which takes a column of the data.frame and one element of the vector of starting positions, performs the `rollapply` on the subsetted data, reverses the series and converts it to zoo.  Using `Map` apply it to the data giving a list of zoo series.  `cbind` on zoo series will insert `NA`s at the end of each so all we have left is to reverse them back and convert them to data.frame:

```
roll <- function(x, st) {
  zoo(rev(rollapplyr(x[st:length(x)], 12, sd, na.rm = TRUE, by = 12, fill = NULL)))
}

st <- c(1, 12)
m <- do.call(cbind, Map(roll, dat, st))
data.frame(lapply(as.list(m), rev), check.names = FALSE)
```

Next time please use `set.seed(...)` to make the code in the question reproducible.

Comment: My initial data frame is composed of columns named with a combination of numbers, characters and dots. Ex: `1001.AFG.2.R`. Your function returns a data frame with modified column names  such as `X1001.AFG.2.R`. Is there a way to insert a `check.names=FALSE` somewhere?

Comment: See revised answer (last line of code is the only one changed).